# Case to check if previous record matches last record

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a query result like the one below. I wish to add a column in the query result that will flag as 1 if the [FinishTime] of the last record related to same [Machine] has the same [StartTime] as the current record.

So for example, in the table below, there is a flag=1 for row 5 ([Machine]=RD103) because it has the same start-time as for it's last record entry (row 3).

```
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|OID|Machine|StartTime|EndTime|DelayName|Consecutive Delay Flag|
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|1  |RD101  |20:00    |20:20  |A        |0                     |
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|2  |RD102  |21:00    |22:00  |A        |0                     |
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|3  |RD103  |23:00    |23:20  |B        |0                     |
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|4  |RD101  |20:20    |20:45  |C        |1                     |
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|5  |RD103  |23:20    |23:25  |A        |1                     |
+---+-------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: The table formatting isnt coming out too right there. Will try to upload an image if I can get enough reputation status

Comment: no need, I fixed the formatting with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great example of what analytic functions do - they don't force you to group your results (in other words - they still produce a single result per row), but you can have values that relate to other rows.

In your case, the `LAG` function should do the trick:

```
SELECT oid, machine, starttime, endtime, delayname, 
       CASE WHEN starttime = 
                 LAG (starttime) OVER (PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY starttime) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS flag
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Wow thanks for such a quick response. I will try this in the AM and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Ok finally got to test it...this worked great. I had to make one small change: Lag(endtime). Thank you very much indeed